tengo un error al intentar usar th:input en spring boot con maven dentro de un formulario
Tengo este error en la plantilla HTML del formulario, al parecer podria ser una insconsistencia en el modelo, pero no he visto errores en el modelo, no he podido probar si esta todo funcionando bien, por el error en el formulario, quité el th:input por solo input pero los datos no se estan enviando a la vista
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/formulariopymes.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/formulariopymes.html]")
Formulario html
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Formulario Pyme</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/pyme}" th:object="${pyme}" method="post">
        <div>
            <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
            <input type="text" id="nombre" th:field="*{nombre}" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="descripcion">Descripción:</label>
            <input type="text" id="descripcion" th:field="*{descripcion}" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="categoria">Categoría:</label>
            <input type="text" id="categoria" th:field="*{categoria}" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" th:field="*{email}" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="telefono">Teléfono:</label>
            <input type="text" id="telefono" th:field="*{telefono}" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="direccion">Dirección:</label>
            <input type="text" id="direccion" th:field="*{direccion}" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

Controlador
package com.example.demo.controllers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import entity.Pyme;


@Controller
public class PymeController {

    
      @GetMapping({"/pymes"})
      public String listPymes(Model model) {
          return "forms/listarPymes";
      }
      @GetMapping("/formulariopymes")
        public String showForm(Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("pyme", new Pyme());
            return "formulariopymes";
        }

      
      @PostMapping("/pyme")
        public String submitForm(@ModelAttribute Pyme pyme,Model model) {
           
          System.out.println(pyme.getNombre());
            model.addAttribute("pyme", pyme);
            return "forms/listarPymes";
        }
 
    
}


Modelo
package entity;

public class Pyme {

    
    private String descripcion;
    private String nombre; 
    private String rubro;
    private String email; 
    private Integer numero;
    private String comunaDelivery;
    
    
    
    
    public Pyme() {
        super();
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.rubro = rubro;
        this.email = email;
        this.numero = numero;
        this.comunaDelivery = comunaDelivery;
    }
    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }
    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public String getRubro() {
        return rubro;
    }
    public void setRubro(String rubro) {
        this.rubro = rubro;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public Integer getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }
    public void setNumero(Integer numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }
    public String getComunaDelivery() {
        return comunaDelivery;
    }
    public void setComunaDelivery(String comunaDelivery) {
        this.comunaDelivery = comunaDelivery;
    }
    
    
    
    
}
    

lo que quiero hacer es poder mostar los datos en la vista y no puedo
Vista
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    


<body class="text-center">
    

    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          
          <th scope="col">Descripcion</th>
          <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
          <th scope="col">Rubro</th>
          <th scope="col">Email</th>
          <th scope="col">Numero</th>
          <th scope="col">Comuna delivery</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr th:each="pyme : ${pymes}">
        
        
         <td th:text="${pyme.descripcion}"></td>
         <td th:text="${pyme.nombre}"></td>
         <td th:text="${pyme.rubro}"></td>
         <td th:text="${pyme.email}"></td>
         <td th:text="${pyme.numero}"></td>
         <td th:text="${pyme.comunaDelivery}"></td>
        </tr>
       
      </tbody>
    </table>

</body>

</html>


pon la traza completa ya que como tal no muestras la causa del error
